# Angular 2/4 Error handling in forkjoin url

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, fork-join

I am usimg angular 2 and  i am using forkjoin for one of the scenario where i have to execute multiple rest calls in parallel.Following is my function

```
 private getBatchObservableData(data: Array<Widget>): Observable<any> {
    let observableBatch = [];
    data.forEach(widget => {
      observableBatch.push(this._http.get(widget.apiPath).delay(500).map((data) => data.json()).share())
    });
    return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
  }
```

This is working perfectly fine.But when any one of the rest call fails the wholeforkjoin fails.So is there any way to emit values of those rest calls and just log which failed. ?? Please help.

Comment: Catch and emit any errors (as values) on the composed HTTP observables using `catch(error => Observable.of(error))` and then test the values in the array emitted by `forkJoin` to see if any are `Error` instances.

Comment: This  will basically help me to log the error.But what about those rest calls which succeeded ? Is there any way to obtain that and display ?

Comment: Which calls succeeded would be obvious, you'd have non-`Error` values in the array for those and `Error` values for any that failed. I'll write an answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `catch` to prevent errors bubbling up to the `forkJoin` call, you can re-emit them as values and can inspect the values in `forkJoin`'s optional project function:

```js
private getBatchObservableData(data: Array<Widget>): Observable<any> {
  let observableBatch = [];
  data.forEach(widget => observableBatch.push(this._http
    .get(widget.apiPath)
    .delay(500)
    .map(data => data.json())
    .catch(error => Observable.of(error))
  ));
  return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch,
    (...results) => ({
      failed: results.map(r => r instanceof Error ? r : null),
      succeeded: results.map(r => r instanceof Error ? null : r)
    })
  );
}
```

The above example will emit an object containing two arrays, each will contain the same number of elements as the `data` array:

- the elements in `failed` will contain an `Error` if the corresponding request failed and `null` otherwise.
- the elements in `succeeded` will contain the data if the corresponding request succeeded and `null` otherwise.

It should be easy to re-arrange things if you need to do things a little differently.

Comment: Even to  make your error handling irrespective of what type of error object thrown by http call, you can wrap the error object in to your application specific error object. Example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7xqy8g